# dictionary in flask_jwt_extended create_access_token

Tags: python, flask, jwt

How can i use dictionary in token identity with flask_jwt_extended.
Any suggestions for pass multiple values in token?

```
create_access_token(identity=????)
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes this is totally can be done by passing a dictionary like:

```
create_access_token(identity= {"name":"Hello", "age":35} )
```

and this would work by implementing a callback function decorated with `user_identity_loader`. The callback function should take one argument and returns JSON string:

```
jwt = JWTManager(app)

import json 

@jwt.user_identity_loader
def user_maker(obj):
    return json.dumps(obj)
```

[read more](http://#%20https://flask-jwt-extended.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/#flask_jwt_extended.JWTManager.user_identity_loader)